# CSS Add separator on list

Tags: css

I want to add separator (image) to my list at CSS, how to add this?

```
li{
list-style:none;
background-image:url("SlicingImage/button_unselect.png");
height: 53px;
width: 180px;
}
```

separator :

```
url("SlicingImage/separator.png")
```

Pic

[image] [image]

HTML

```
 <p><img src="SlicingImage/logo.png"/>
 <li>Coffee</li>
 <li>Tea</li>
 <li>Coca Cola</li>
```

Comment: What kind of list? Any example code of the actual list?

Comment: You need to give up a bit more then that. Show us the HTML of the list with relevant CSS.

Comment: IMAGES : left : expected, right : my result now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options availible
    
    Button 1
    Separator 1
    Button 2
    Separator 1
    Button 3

```
.buttons{
list-style:none;
background-image:url("SlicingImage/button_unselect.png");
height: 53px;
width: 180px;
}
.separator{
background-image:url("SlicingImage/separator.png");
width:5px; /*select your width */
height:53px; /*select your height */
```

}